# Detect and Display of operating system using Perl

Tags: perl

I want to display my computer's operating system using Perl. I thought the following would do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $os = $^O;
print "$os\n";
```

But the output I got is

```
linux
```

I want the output to be displayed as

```
Windows XP
```

How to do this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it, are you on a Linux machine or Windows?  You have a shebang at the top of your script.

Comment: All of my Perl scripts that run on Windows have a shebang line. Why is that confusing?

Comment: What? You have a very broken Perl if `$^O` has `linux` on a Windows machine. (It should have the value `MSWin32`, at which point you could use functions in the [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32) module to get more info.)

Comment: @SinanÜnür I meant for Linux at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for

```
use CGI                 qw( );
use HTTP::BrowserDetect qw( );

my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header('text/plain');

my $bd = HTTP::BrowserDetect->new($cgi->user_agent());
print $bd->os_string(), "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the **uname()** function that the [POSIX module provides for you](https://metacpan.org/module/POSIX).

Comment: Unfortunately, the `uname` module doesn't provide a standard place for the name. It returns an array, and the documentation states: _Note that the actual meanings of the various fields are not that well standardized, do not expect any great portability._

Answer (score 2):

All Perl distributions come with the [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) module. This module is a bit rickety because it imports the hash `%Config`, but it's an easy way to get access to all sorts of Perl configuration information.

```
use Config;  # This exports a %Config hash

print "My OS is $Config{osname}\n";
print "My OS version is $Config{osvers}\n";
print "My Architecture Family is $Config{archname}\n";

#
# Print out all of the keys, and see which one looks like one
# you can use. "ld" is actually a rather nice value
#
for my $key (sort keys %Config) {
    no warnings qw(uninitialized); # Some elements have undef values
    print qq($key: "$Config{$key}"\n);
}
```

Comment: `print "$key: ", defined($Config{$key}) ? qq{"$Config{$key}"} : "[undef]", "\n";` would make more sense than silencing warnings.